# Include port to virtual host on macbook m1

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

I am using Passport in PHP Laravel project. When I send request with Postman the request crashes. I created a virtual host to prevent this situation. The virtual host I created is working but I can't include the port in this address.

For example the project is running at 127.0.0.1:8000/login.

The address of the virtual host I created is macbookm1.test

I need to type macbook.test:8000/login for this address to see login. How do I include the 8000 port added later in the macbookm1.test address?

The files modified for this process are as follows.

**For /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file**

```
Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**For /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test"
    ServerName macbookm1.test:80
    ServerAlias www.macbookm1.test
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test"
    ServerName macbookm1.test:8000
    ServerAlias www.macbookm1.test
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-error_log"

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test"
    ServerName macbookm1.test:8001
    ServerAlias www.macbookm1.test
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.macbookm1.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
</br>
```

**And when i type sudo apachectl restart. I am encountering the following error**

```
</br>
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for macbook-Air 
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
</br>
```

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "How do I include the 8000 port added later in the macbookm1.test address?"? You just did exactly that in the sentence before that: "I need to type macbook.test:8000/login". You specify the port number as part of the URL. And the ServerName stays `ServerName macbookm1.test` in all cases. If you want with a `ServerAlias www.macbookm1.test`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.